# Fluid disappears on the first few frames

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image: fluidsimulation]

I can't figure out why the fluid just completely disappears on the first few frames. It's happened on the last 3 tries for a beach project I'm working on.
Here is the file:
[image]
Also I have tried deleting the cache, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I tried you file and can't reproduce your problem. Try to delete the cache folder (it's in the same folder as your file) and bake again.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141229/fluid-simulation-resolution-issues

Comment: Clearing the cache helped. Thanks a lot