# The top of the fluid disappears if I turn resolution above 80

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

[image: Fluid Simulation Issues]

Whenever I bake this fluid sim for a beach at a resolution lower than 80, it works fine. But whenever I turn the resolution of the fluid up to a number above 80, the top of the fluid disappears. Does anyone know why this happens/how to fix it? Here is the file:[image]

I had another thread of this same question, but the suggestions did not fix the problem.

Comment: Hi. Isn't this exactly the same as your other question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141210/fluid-disappears-on-the-first-few-frames

Comment: @RayMairlot Yes, when I posted it the first time I was under a guest account so I could not edit it, so I created an account and reposted it. Also I was not aware of the fact that a lower resolution worked fine when I posted the first time.

Comment: To merge your accounts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336512/is-there-a-way-to-combine-or-merge-stack-exchange-accounts

Comment: @cegaton thanks :)